# Cache Spannable Strings for RecyclerView

Tags: android, caching, android-recyclerview, spannablestring

I have a Recyclerview which holds a lot of messages, similar to a chat screen.

In each list item, I have a `TextView` in which I set `Spannable` strings. The strings contains images and text and sometimes just text. The method I have to replace some chars in the strings with `Drawables` can get quite costly when there are a ton of characters needed to be replaced by images, a noticeable jitter/lag starts to appear `onScroll`. I have also placed the costly method in a `AsyncTask` which improved the speed of the RecyclerView a lot.

**Question:**

Is it possible to cache a `Spannable` object with all of its metadata? If the user scrolls up a screen or two and then back down, I want to try and avoid the `Spannables` being built every time the row is rendered on screen.

If Caching is possible, I'll even go a bit further to implement a "Pre-Cache" method which builds and caches the Spannables on a separate thread so if the user scrolls up and down, it will simply be loaded from the cache rather than building it if it exists resulting in a "faster" or "smoother" user experience.

**Drawables**

The drawables are loaded/created from `FilePaths`, Inserted as an `ImageSpan` into the spannable string after which is set to the `TextView` in the AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I wanted to.

-1. Created a class `LruSpannableCache` extending to `LruCache`

and override the `sizeOf` method

```
@override
protected int sizeOf(Object key, Object value)
{
    //The cache size will be measured in kilobytes rather than number of items.
    return ((CacheSpannable)value).size() / 1024;
}
```

-2. Created an Object `CacheSpannable`

```
public class CacheSpannable
{
    private int key;
    private ISpannable text;

    // Getters and Setters for key and text...

    public int size()
    {
        return text.length(); //Can also add the byte length for `key`
    }
}
```

-3. Finally created a class with static methods to `add` and `get` cached spannables

```
private static LruCache spannableCache;
private static final int cacheSize = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024 / 6;

public static void addSpannable(int key, CacheSpannable value)
{
    if (spannableCache == null) spannableCache = new LruSpannableCache(cacheSize);

    if (getSpannable(key) == null)
    {
        spannableCache.put(key, value);
    }
}

public static CacheSpannable getSpannable(int key)
{
    if (spannableCache == null) spannableCache = new LruSpannableCache(cacheSize);

    return (CacheSpannable)spannableCache.get(key);
}
```

Then to use it, I simply check if the `Spannable` is cached (`getSpannable(key) != null`) then set it to the `TextView` or if not, build it, add to cache and then set it to the `TextView`.

Next step would be to implement a Disk Cache to persist the spannables indefinitely

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend looking at `setItemViewCacheSize(int)` method of `RecyclerView`. Next, if you have a lot of drawable in your `Spannable` maybe it worth to check the size of this drawables they could be too big. Another idea is to precompile the whole list of your items before passing it to `bindViewHolder`.